# Unable to assign a role to user assigned identity through Azure Run books

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-runbook

By using the below command, trying to assign a role to the managed identity using PowerShell runbook(5.1 Runtime version).

```
$roleAssignment = New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx' -Scope '/subscriptions/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxxxx' -RoleDefinitionName 'Contributor'
```

When we execute the runbook we ran into the below error.

```
Exception of type 'Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException' was thrown.
```

But, When executed the same command from local PowerShell ISE we are able to assign the role with out any fail.

How to make runbook to assign the role to the user assigned identity.

Can any one help me solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Unable to assign a role to user assigned identity through Azure Run books (1).html

Unable to assign a role to user assigned identity through Azure Run books

> Exception of type ‘Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException’ was thrown.

***To resolve the above error, I would suggest you try to follow the below workaround that worked for me: -***

***Go to Azure AD --> App registrations --> Select your app --> API Permissions --> Add permission --> Microsoft Graph (You can select any Azure resource for which you want to grant permissions for) --> Application Permissions --> Directory --> Directory.Read.All***
Then grant admin consent for the selected permissions for that particular resource.

[image]

[image]

Here, you can select other services which you are using, also in ‘Request API Permissions’ other than Microsoft Graph, you can use other APIs that you are working since the process is same as shown in the below snapshot: -

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]